# Dissolving features to only have multiparts when they are within 100 feet of one another

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, dissolve, multipart

I  want to have a selection of parcels that is dissolved by land owner and within 3 miles of a polyline. If the same owner owns parcels on opposite sides of a road (within 100 feet or so), I want the parcel to be a multipart. However, I don't want to have multiparts for parcels with the same owner that are >1 mile of each other.

This is part of a large model that I'm putting together. I'm sure python is the answer but I'm still very green with it. Is there a series of tools that will accomplish this?

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3 with the Advanced License.

Comment: Could you tell us what software you are using?

Comment: Hi Arcmap 10.3 with the advanced license. Thanks

Comment: I would do this in C# (or VB.net) ArcObjects. Something you can look at is buffer by 50 feet, dissolve by owner, generate near table with a distance of 0, exclude records where near.owner <> parcel.owner, join near table with parcels, calc dissolved ID then dissolve the parcels by owner and dissolve ID.. is that a path you'd like to take?

Comment: Spatial join one to many + field calculator will do the job. I'll post solution on Monday.  TGIF

Comment: Yes the buffer and dissolve method was the path I took.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this by buffering the parcel data 50 feet and using the dissolve function within the tool to only dissolve the buffers with the same land owner. I then ran a multipart to singlepart. Then, calculated a unique ID for each polygon (DissolveID).

I then ran a spatial join, one to many, of the parcels within the buffer area to calculate over the DissolveID field. Then dissolved the parcels based on that DissolveID.